# Adding objects to an arraylist in java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, addition

I am trying to write a solitiare game on java. I'm trying to add the card objects to my arraylist but the MakeDeck function is not working properly.

```
public class PileOfCards {
public ArrayList<Card> pile = new ArrayList<Card>();
Card tempo;

public PileOfCards() {
  pile = new ArrayList<Card>();

}

public void MakeDeck() {

    for (int i=0;i<13;i++){
        tempo = new Card(i+1, "FaceDown", "Clubs");
        pile.add(tempo);

    }
    for (int j=0;j<13;j++){
        tempo = new Card(j+1, "FaceDown", "Diamonds");
        pile.add(tempo);
}
    for (int k=0;k<13;k++){
        tempo = new Card(k+1, "FaceDown", "Hearts");
        pile.add(tempo);
    }
    for (int l=0;l<13;l++){
        tempo = new Card(l+1, "FaceDown", "Spades");
        pile.add(tempo);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to print the values it prints "0, null, null" , 52 times. What is the problem? It looks like I can't reach to the ArrayList, but I don't know why.

Edited:

Card constructor:

```
   public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
    valueTemp = value;
    suitTemp = suit;
    statusTemp = status;
    }
```

Print function:

```
 public void printPile(){
     for(int i=0;i<pile.size();i++){
     System.out.print(pile.get(i).status);
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(pile.get(i).suit);
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(pile.get(i).value);
     System.out.printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Without seeing the code where you're doing the print-out, we can't really help you. I have a few theories about what's wrong, but first, please add the code that isn't working to your original post.

Comment: What does your print statement look like? And can you provide the constructor for `Card`

Comment: Just a comment to say that a) you do not need a new variable for each loop, b) if you going to add `1` to the loop variable then why not do `for (int i=1; i <= 13; i++) ...`

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your print routine.  The above code appears OK.

Comment: I added the print function code and the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in your `Card` constructor; the assignments are the wrong way around.

You want

```
public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
    value = valueTemp;
    suit = suitTemp;
    status = statusTemp;
}
```

The other way around doesn't set the fields equal to the parameters, it sets the parameters equal to the fields. Specifically, what you had before

```
public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
   valueTemp = value;
   suitTemp = suit;
   statusTemp = status;
}
```

sets `valueTemp` to `value`, `suitTemp` to `suit`, and `statusTemp` to `status`, when you actually wanted to do the other way around in your constructor.

Comment: ^ I noticed this as well

Answer (score 2):

```
public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
  valueTemp = value;
  suitTemp = suit;
  statusTemp = status;
}
```

All those assignments are back to front. You are assigning *to* the parameters instead of *from* them. It is customary to write it like this:

```
public Card(int value, String suit, String status) {
  this.value = value;
  this.suit = suit;
  this.status = status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignments are backwards.

`lValue = rValue`;

`lValue` is the thing you want to set while `rValue` is the data you want it to become.

When you did:

```
public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
    valueTemp = value;
    suitTemp = suit;
    statusTemp = status;
}
```

You're changing the parameters `valueTemp`, `suitTemp`, and `statusTemp` which you passed in as parameters to whatever `value`, `suit`, and `status` are.

To fix this, flip around the values you're assigning like so:

```
public Card(int valueTemp, String suitTemp, String statusTemp) {
    value = valueTemp;
    suit = suitTemp;
    status = statusTemp;
}
```