# ArrayList lists null instead of instances of the object

Tags: java

```
public class Library{
    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBook()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter title of the book: ");
        String title = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the author: ");
        String author = sc.nextLine();

        String bookID = bookID();

        Book b = new Book(author,title,bookID,true);
        books.add(b);

        System.out.println( title + " by "+ author +" added to library.");
        System.out.println("Book ID: " + bookID);

    }

    public void listBooks()
    {
        for (Book temp : books)
        {
            if (temp.loanStatus() == true) System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println(temp.getTitle() + " by " + temp.getAuthor()+
                "ID: " + temp.getID());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Book class:

```
public class Book {

    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String ID;
    private boolean loanRecord = true;

    public Book(String au, String titl, String id, boolean loan)
    {
        au = author;
        titl = title;
        loan = loanRecord;  
        id = ID;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public String getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public boolean loanStatus()
    {
        return loanRecord;
    }

    public void checkoutBook()
    {
        loanRecord = false;
    }

    public void returnBook()
    {
        loanRecord = true;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I call my `listBooks()` method to list all of the books added to the `books` ArrayList, every `Book` object that I have added comes out as `null` instead of the desired string instances that I expect.

Comment: What do you mean by *comes out as null instead of the desired string instances that I want*? What part, specifically, is null? If its any of your book methods such as `getTitle` or `getAuthor`, you may not be setting those fields properly in your `Book` constructor. We would have to see the `Book` class to know for sure.

Comment: If `books` actually contained `null` values, you'd get NPEs. Guess yor `Book` class hosts the problem.

Comment: Could you show your `Book` class?

Comment: I added my Book class. I wasn't sure if it was necessary to show it to you guys or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding objects to an arraylist in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485496/adding-objects-to-an-arraylist-in-java). That one was also a "adding stuff to an ArrayList but printing out null because assignments wrong way around" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You swapped your assignments in your constructor.

It should be:

```
public Book(String au, String titl, String id, boolean loan){   
  author = au;    
  title = titl;   
  loanRecord = loan;  
  ID = id;    
}
```

As a quick note, you could override the `toString` method in your `Book` class and simply do:

```
for (Book temp : books){
     if (temp.loanStatus()) 
          System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Lol, I edited my answer to suggest the toString override at the same time as you^^

Answer (score 3):

The constructor is wrong:

```
public Book(String au, String titl, String id, boolean loan)
{   au = author;    titl = title;   loan = loanRecord;  id = ID;    }
```

should be:

```
public Book(String au, String titl, String id, boolean loan)
{   author = au;    title = titl;   loanRecord = loan;  ID = id;    }
```

Another thing to consider would be to override the default toString() method in the Book class. Then you could print the objects using just:

```
for(Book b : books)
  System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refactor your Book class ,

```
public class Book {

    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String ID; // the name can be changed to id , if you are fine with it
    private boolean loanRecord = true;

    public Book(String author, String title, String id, boolean loan) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.ID = id;
        this.loanRecord = loan;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public boolean loanStatus() {
        return loanRecord;
    }

    public void checkoutBook() {
        loanRecord = false;

    }

    public void returnBook() {
        loanRecord = true;
    }
}
```